# How can I put rows of MySQL data under the appropriate titles using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have the following MySQL table structure:

```
num field company phone     website

1   Gas   abcd    123456789 abcd.com
2   Water efgh    987654321 efgh.com
3   Water ijkl    321654987 ijkl.com
4   Heat  mnop    987654321 mnop.com
5   Gas   qrst    123789654 qrst.com
...
```

Is it possible with PHP (maybe using some mixture of `GROUP_BY` and `ORDER_BY`) to echo the data to the screen in the following format:

```
Gas:
abcd       qrst
123456789  123789654
abcd.com   qrst.com

Water:
efgh       ijkl
987654321  321654987
efgh.com   ijkl.com

Heat:
mnop
321654987
mnop.com
```

The exact format of it isn't important.  I just need for the different rows of data to be listed under the appropriate field with none of the fields repeated.  I've been trying to figure this out for a while now, but I'm new to PHP and I can't seem to figure out how to do this, if it's even possible, or if there's a better way to organize my data to make it easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid performing a "Gas" query, a "Water" query and a "Heat" query, you could order the results by "field" and then handle the display in PHP...

```
SELECT
    Field,
    Company,
    Phone,
    Website
FROM
    tblYourTable
ORDER BY
    Field
```

In your PHP loop, you would need to keep tabs on your current "Field" and start a new list when it changes. For example:

```
$CurrentField = '';

... loop

if ($MyData->Field != $CurrentField) {
    $CurrentField = $MyData->Field;
    ....
}

... end loop
```

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that you know how to retrieve MySQL data into an array... so, we have:

```
[0] {
    num => 1,
    field => "Gas",
    company => "abcd",
    phone => "123456789",
    website => "abcd.com"
    }
[1] ... (so on)
```

Then create a loop like:

```
foreach($data as $row) {
   $service = $row["field"]; //Water, Gas, etc...
   unset($row["field"]); //do not add this
   foreach($row as $key => $value) {
       $field[$service][$key][] = $value;
   }
}
```

The resulting array will be something like:

```
$field["Gas"]["company"][0] = "abcd";
$field["Gas"]["company"][1] = "qrst";
$field["Water"]["company"][0] = "efgh";
...
$field["Gas"]["phone"][0] = "123456789";
$field["Gas"]["phone"][1] = "123789654";
$field["Water"]["phone"][0] = "987654321";
...
```

In that way you can then generate the output:

```
foreach($field as $service => $infoarr) {
   echo $service."\n";
   foreach($infoarr as $info => $datarr) {
       foreach($datarr as $datum) {
          echo $datum."\t"; 
       }
       echo "\n";
   }
   echo "\n";
}
```

Theorically (untested) will output:

```
Gas 
abcd qrst 
123456789 123789654 

Water 
efgh ...
```

I hope you find it useful... There should be a better way, but I didn't thought
too much about it...

Comment: I like this method too!  The other one seems like it will be just a bit faster and simpler, but if I run into any severe problems with it, I'll give this a shot.